# Entity Framework Passing Table Value in Parameter Of a Function

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a requirement, where I check a particular string value within a particular column of 2 and more than 2 table (the column name of different table is same)
and if the string is present in any one of table column it will return false.

```
public Boolean CheckAirCraftType(String AirCraftTypeCode, ref ExceptionEntity ExceptionEntityObject)
{
    Boolean InUse = false;
    try
    {
        var QueryTFLTORD = (from tflord in RoyalFleetEntities.TFLTORDHs.Where(a => a.ACFT_TYPE_CODE == AirCraftTypeCode)
                            select tflord).ToList();

        var QueryTAIRCRFT = (from taircraft in RoyalFleetEntities.TAIRCRFTs.Where(a => a.ACFT_TYPE_CODE == AirCraftTypeCode)
                             select taircraft).ToList();

        var queryTFLTORDH = (from tfltordh in RoyalFleetEntities.TFLTORDHs.Where(a => a.ACFT_TYPE_CODE == AirCraftTypeCode)
                             select tfltordh).ToList();

        if (QueryTFLTORD.Count > 0 || QueryTAIRCRFT.Count > 0 || queryTFLTORDH.Count > 0)
        {
            InUse = true;
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ExceptionObject)
    {
        ..
    }

    return InUse;
}
```

It is working well, but I want to customized my code so that it can be reusable.
So I want to pass table name [in my case "**TFLTORDHs**",**TAIRCRFTs**] in the parameter of a function, and it will check whether the string is present in that table or not?

How can I achieve it? Please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, this is not going to be the answer you wanted.
You may create an interface, and then ask for the implementations of it.

```
public interface IAirCraftUseCheck
{
    bool IsAirCraftUsed(string airCraftCode);
}

public class RoyalFleetEntities : IAirCraftUseCheck
{
    bool IsAirCraftUsed(string airCraftCode)
    {
        bool InUse = false;
        try
        {
            var QueryTFLTORD = (from tflord in RoyalFleetEntities.TFLTORDHs.Where(a => a.ACFT_TYPE_CODE == AirCraftTypeCode)
                                select tflord).ToList();

            var QueryTAIRCRFT = (from taircraft in RoyalFleetEntities.TAIRCRFTs.Where(a => a.ACFT_TYPE_CODE == AirCraftTypeCode)
                                 select taircraft).ToList();

            var queryTFLTORDH = (from tfltordh in RoyalFleetEntities.TFLTORDHs.Where(a => a.ACFT_TYPE_CODE == AirCraftTypeCode)
                                 select tfltordh).ToList();



            if (QueryTFLTORD.Count > 0 || QueryTAIRCRFT.Count > 0 || queryTFLTORDH.Count > 0)
            {
                InUse = true;
            }

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ExceptionObject)
        {
           ..
        }


        return InUse;       
    }
}
```

You can use Reflection or some libraries like StructureMap to go through all the classes that implement that interface, and then invoke the method and check the result if it is in use.

Why go this way, because in the future some other module that you are unaware of may use the Aircraft and it can even use a completely different database but still depend on the same aircraft object that you are controlling now. And if they implement that interface then you still know that it is in use or not.